# Why does sugar dissolve faster in hot water compared to cold water?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, physical-chemistry, states-of-matter

Why does sugar dissolve faster in hot water compared to cold water?

Comment: http://www.middleschoolchemistry.com/lessonplans/chapter5/lesson6

Comment: Quoting from the [tag:general-physics] tag description you were shown as you were tagging your question: DO NOT USE THIS TAG if a more descriptive tag applies.

Comment: Please do not edit questions in a way that completely changes their meaning, and in particular invalidates existing answers. If the answers have led you to new questions, please *ask a new question*.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to have to respectfully disagree with Pranjal Rana.

The reason that sugar dissolves more quickly in hot water than in cold water has to do with the kinetic energy of the particles.

The faster (hotter) the water molecules are moving, the more energy they give to the sugar molecules when they collide with them.

Think about it this way: a sugar crystal is just a lot of sugar molecules stuck together. You dissolve the crystal you need to hit the molecules with enough force to break them off of the rest of the crystal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you like to mention why did you disagree with Pranjal Rana's answer?

Comment: Dissolution is a function of many factors, and mean space between solvent molecules is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I will explain it with the help of Le Chatelier principle. It states that the rate of reaction depends on the temperature. If the reaction is exothermic, then decrease of temperature will increase the rate to compensate the effect caused by decrease of temperature. However the rate will decrease if the temperature is increased, so that the equilibrium is again obtained. Similarly it happens with endothermic reactions but inversely. 
I hope I was able to answer your question.